# Push notification not working for iOS, .php file gives connection error

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

For APNS, I had tried with my certificate and web script (.php file) and its working everything fine. Now I am trying the same thing with client provided certificate, he has sent me his .p12 file, I have done all correct stpes and generated .pem file for server but its not working. I didn't get why its happening?? Any one has an idea about it? Here is my server file which I am using to send notifications.

```
    <?PHP
if($_POST['message'])
{   
    $deviceToken = '<my device token id>';
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
    $payload = '{
                    "aps" : 

                        { "alert" : "'.$message.'",
                          "badge" : 3,
                          "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
                        } 
                }';
    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '<my passPharse>');
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
    if(!$fp){
        print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Notifications sent!";
    }
    $devArray = array();
    $devArray[] = $deviceToken;
    foreach($devArray as $deviceToken){
        $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
        //print "sending message :" . $payload . "n";
        fwrite($fp, $msg);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
<form action="send-notification.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="message" maxlength="100">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Notification">
</form>
```

This file working well with my .pem file but giving error "Failed to connect 0" with my client's file. I can't able to find the reason for it.

If any one having idea of it then please guide/show me path to solve the problem, Please.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its was a bug with .pem file. If you not providing the correct password while creating the .pem file from .p12 then the file will be created but it will not work. I checked that process with remote login and caught the issue.

Thank you all for your help and support :)

Answer (score 0):

i think thats issue of p12 files if its not making properly then this error will came and to make sure it again just use follow code to generate pem file then also if not working then its  wrong p12 file

`openssl pkcs12 -in server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.p12 -out server_certificates_bundle_sandbox.pem -nodes -clcerts`

Comment: hello iKambad. Thank you for help but when I do this its just asked me for password and not for passphrase. We are using passphrase in our php file for .cem file, so what it will be or can I remove that or pass just empty string for that?? Please let me know.

Comment: I have created .pem file with this command, replace it over server, and try like this for sendNotification.php.  stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'myPwd');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'password', '');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'password', 'myPwd');  but its still not working. What do you think? Any suggestions for correcting this?? -Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I send notifications without .pem file? or can I use .pfx as .pem?

Comment: no when you make pem file via code at that time they ask you for password dont wrote anything in that i mean password is blank when making pem or p12

Comment: you must have to use .pem file and check also that your path is also correct

Comment: Hi I guess its problem with my client certificate so I asked for new. My personal APNS is working but there is also on problem that its not showing Budge icon, any conditions needs to be check?

Comment: My payload is as follows,  do I making any mistake here?? $payload = '{
     "aps" :       
      { "alert" : "'.$message.'",
        "badge" : 2,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
      } 
    }';